# For Loop in python loops an unnecessary amount of times

Tags: python

I am trying to create an ATM machine using a `for` loop that will print out 100s, 20s, 10s and 1s, but my for loop is looping excessively and will get me the right amount of change but will loop through the 100s 20 times.

```
import math

withdrawl = int(input("How much money do you want to withdraw?: "))
count = 0
for x in range(withdrawl):
    if x >= 100:
        print(math.trunc(withdrawl/100)," $100 Dollar Bills",)
        withdrawl = withdrawl - (math.trunc(withdrawl/100)*100)
        count+= 1
else:
    print("0 $100 Dollar Bills")
for x in range(x-1,withdrawl):
    if x >= 20:
        print(math.trunc(withdrawl/20)," $20 Dollar Bills")
        withdrawl = withdrawl - (math.trunc(withdrawl/20)*20)
for x in range(withdrawl):
    if x >= 10:
        print(math.trunc(withdrawl/10)," $10 Dollar Bills")
        withdrawl = withdrawl - (math.trunc(withdrawl/10)*10)
for x in range(withdrawl):
    if x >= 5:
        print(math.trunc(withdrawl/5)," $5 Dollar Bills")
        withdrawl = withdrawl - (math.trunc(withdrawl/5)*5)
for x in range(withdrawl):
    if x >= 1:
        print(math.trunc(withdrawl/1)," $1 Dollar Bills")
        withdrawl = withdrawl - (math.trunc(withdrawl/1)*1)

print ("Thank you for using our upgraded ATM machine!")
```

Comment: Can you pls re-format your code? if and else are not indented correctly

Comment: `for x in range(withdrawl):` will create a range object at the start, e.g. from 0 to 9999. When you then change withdrawal within the loop, the range object doesn't change.

Comment: You're basically expecting us to debug your program for you... Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and use [PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to help you track the execution of your program. Anyway you never `break` out of the loops so they will always execute `withdrawl` amount of times...

Answer (score 2):

I think for your purpose for loop is not necessary. You can try something like

```
n = 838

hundred, n = divmod(n, 100)
twenty, n  = divmod(n, 20)
ten, n     = divmod(n, 10)
five, n    = divmod(n, 5)
one        = n 

print(hundred, twenty, ten, five, one)
```

`>>> 8 1 1 1 3`

Comment: you might even look into `numpy.divmod()`, as this returns both `//` and `%` simultaniously.

Answer (score 0):

Following `@Girish Dattatray Hegde`'s idea, you can have a dictionary and get the amounts you need by looping over the dictionary's keys, using the same `//`, `%` operations as `@Girish Dattatray Hegde`:

```py
amount = 486.51
bill_dict = {
    500: 0,  200: 0,  100:0,
    50: 0,   20: 0,   10:0,
    5: 0,    2: 0,    1:0,
    0.50: 0, 0.20: 0, 0.10:0,
    0.05: 0, 0.02: 0, 0.01:0,
}
for k in bill_dict.keys():
    if amount / float(k) >= 1:
        bill_dict[k] = int(amount // k)
    amount = round(amount % k, 2)
```